# Java or Kotlin Alternative to JS ParseObject.extend

Tags: java, android, kotlin, parse-platform

I'm wanting to port a `JavaScript` code to `Kotlin` or `Java` while using the Android Parse library, but the `Java` Parse library doesn't have the function "[ParseObject.extend()](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.Object.html#.extend)" because what "extend" does in `JavaScript` cannot be done in the `Java` world as far as I could understand. The question is now what would the alternative be, how can I port following code to `Java` or `Kotlin`?:

```
const MyAddress = ParseObject.extend('_MyAddress');
const query = new ParseQuery(MyAddress);
const myAddressRecord = query.get(myAddress);
```

Comment: And what does `extend` do?

Comment: Please refer to this guide (https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#subclasses) and let me know in the case you have any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was following:

```
val builder = ParseQuery.State.Builder<ParseObject>("_MyAddress")
val query = ParseQuery(builder)
val myAddressRecord = query.get(myAddress)
```